# An impressive body of work

Tags: pattern, movies

To commemorate the 71st Primetime Emmy Awards being held today, here is a short and simple puzzle involving TV roles:

1. Cersei Lannister, *Game of Thrones*
2. Alexander Grayson, *Dracula (2013)*
3. Bob Lee Swagger, *Shooter*
4. Douglas Brackman Jr, *L.A. Law*
5. Dr. Beaumont Rosewood Jr, *Rosewood*
6. Norma Louise Bates, *Bates Motel*
7. Eric Taylor, *Friday Night Lights*
8. Sabrina Spellman, *Chilling Adventures of Sabrina*
9. Jen Harding, *Dead to Me*
10. Christopher Ewing, *Dallas (2012)*
11. Olivia Pope, *Scandal*

Each of the above roles has something in common.  What is it?

Note: The list is in a particular order, but it isn't crucial for finding the answer.

Comment: @jmp I didn't think movies tag would be appropriate because the tag description only  mentions movies and not tv shows.

Comment: The tag is probably out of date. Movies/TV/YouTube are practically the same thing these days!

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/9870/revisions

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This must have been quite a fun puzzle to create! The connection between these roles is:

> They are all played by actors/actresses with **body parts** (hence the title) in their name.

Like so:

> 1. Cersei Lannister, *Game of Thrones* = Lena Kathren **HEAD**ey
>  2. Alexander Grayson, *Dracula (2013)* = Jonathan Rhys M**EYE**rs
>  3. Bob Lee Swagger, *Shooter* = Ryan Phil**LIP**pe
>  4. Douglas Brackman Jr, *L.A. Law* = Alan Ra**CHIN**s
>  5. Dr. Beaumont Rosewood Jr, *Rosewood* = Morris **CHEST**nut
>  6. Norma Louise Bates, *Bates Motel* = Vera F**ARM**iga
>  7.  Eric Taylor, *Friday Night Lights* = Kyle C**HAND**ler
>  8. Sabrina Spellman, *Chilling Adventures of Sabrina* = Kiernan S**HIP**ka
>  9. Jen Harding, *Dead to Me* = Christina App**LEG**ate
>  10. Christopher Ewing, *Dallas (2012)* = Jesse Met**CALF**e
>  11. Olivia Pope, *Scandal* = Kerry Wa**SHIN**gton

Pleasingly:

> The list is ordered from the top of the body to the bottom!

Comment: 8 and 9 are out of order for me lol. Very nice puzzle and answer!